# How to remove the spaces in string in javascript

Tags: javascript, spaces, removeall

I would like to avoid spaces from a string in javascript. I would like to remove spaces not only infront and after of the string , instead I would like to remove spaces from the string (front,in between the characters and end).

Thanks in adavance

Comment: This is called normalization.

Comment: just spaces? what about tabs and newlines?

Answer (score 0):

**CODE:**

```
var str = "String String String";
str = str.replace(/ /g,'');  // ' '  -> REMOVE ONLY ' ', NOT \n, \r, \t, and \f
console.log(str);            // '/g' -> GLOBAL or MATCH_ALL or FIND ALL ' '
```

***Note**: Change the `/ /g` to `/\s/g` if you want to include `\n, \r, \t, \f, and " "`*

---

**OUTPUT:**

`StringStringString`

Comment: Probably a little more efficient to use `\s+`.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
var s = "my cool example string";
var s_no_space = s.replace(/ /g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
var str = "a string with spaces";
var nospacesStr = str.replace(/\s/g, ""); // "astringwithspaces"
```